# Can't seem to figure what is giving this error when I am trying to import this .sql file in phpmyadmin. (I am using 000webhost.com)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

Error
SQL query:

### --
-- Database: `workshop`

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `appointments`

CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
`mechanic` int(11) NOT NULL,
`appointment_date` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

MySQL said:

#1044 - Access denied for user 'id17662418_root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. Make the title of your question  more precise

Comment: There are a couple of things that could be wrong here, so I'll start with a basic question: Is the single CREATE TABLE line the only thing in the file? If not, please open up the .sql file in a text editor (not word processor) and search for `information_schema` and see if anything is found. Is it a managed hosting situation or is it a VPS? Are you certain that you have permissions to create a new database, or is it a shared hosting environment where you only get access to one database?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.